# How do I await a HANDLE / SafeHandle?

Tags: c#, task, pinvoke

I have a process `HANDLE` I got from a `P/Invoke`'d API. What is the moral equivalent of `WaitForSingleObject` or `WaitOne` that plays nicely with tasks?

Comment: RegisterWaitForSingleObject perhaps.  Get a better answer by not hiding details about the type of handle and the api, there is no point to that.

Comment: @HansPassant It's a process handle from CreateProcess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would wrap it up in a WaitHandle, like so:

```
    private class MyWaitHandle : System.Threading.WaitHandle {
        public MyWaitHandle(IntPtr handle) {
            this.SafeWaitHandle = new Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeWaitHandle(handle, true   /*change to false if you will manually close your handle*/);
        }
    }
```

Then pass your p/invoked handle into the new `MyWaitHandle` and wait on it normally:

```
using (var myWaitThing = new MyWaitHandle(hSomeUnmanagedHandle)) {
     myWaitThing.WaitOne();
}
```

Not sure what kind of niceties you are looking for when playing with tasks, but if you want a task that completes when your wait event is done, then fire off a `Task` that does nothing but wait for that WaitOne() to return, and then you can await that `Task` like any other.

Comment: There's [`WaitHandleAsyncFactory.FromWaitHandle`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Interop.WaitHandles/Interop/WaitHandleAsyncFactory.cs) in Stephen Cleary's AsyncEx library.

Comment: That's still blocking though, so it's functionally the same as the existing call to WaitForSingleObject :(. I want to not consume a task thread if possible.

Comment: A windows wait handle works on the back-end by blocking a thread until the completion is signaled.  If you are waiting on one, then you are blocking a thread, somewhere.  You can use a dedicated thread, a worker thread from the thread pool, etc., but somewhere a thread is consumed while waiting.  The only way I can think to not use a thread would be to use a `Timer` to callback on a worker thread periodically to poll the wait handle for completion, then use that to signal completion of a Task-- but that isn't very efficient...

Comment: @Tim: Damn, that's unfortunate. I guess if I want to be smarter about this I'll need to coalesce process waits somehow.

Comment: If you are waiting on lots of handles, use `WaitHandle.WaitAny()` to efficiently wait for *any* of your handles to complete using a single thread.

Answer (score 0):

From a performance perspective, `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject` is what you want to use in this situation. The ThreadPool will use a single thread to wait on all objects registered that way.

To use that API with a process handle you need to wrap it into a `WaitHandle`, as demonstrated in Tim's answer.

Making it Task-friendly is a little tricky. Use [WaitHandleAsycFactory.FromWaitHandle](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Interop.WaitHandles/Interop/WaitHandleAsyncFactory.cs) from Stephen Cleary's AsyncEx library or look at the implementation to figure out how to roll your own.